# How can I write a .bat file that will run same .exe file multiple times

Tags: batch-file

I'd like to write a `.bat` file that can run same `.exe` file multiple times with different input files.

Does anyone know how to implement this task? What kind of commands should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example:

```
FOR %v IN (c:\Users\public\videos\*.avi) DO my.exe %v
```

For more information just type

```
for /?
```